# STL algorithm function templates

Tags: c++, stl

The program has to finds an element in a sorted array and implement this function template:

```
bool find(T *p, T value, int &index=null)
```

I have completed a part, but when I try to do the Null part all my number goes to zeros. Also I do not know how to implement the index. Can someone help me please.

```cpp
int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    vector<int>::iterator iter;

    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        numbers.push_back(x);

    cout << "The numbers in the vector are:\n";
    for (iter = numbers.begin(); iter != numbers.end(); iter++)
        cout << *iter << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    iter = find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 5);
    cout << *iter << endl;
```

Comment: You can't have a null reference. If you need something like that use a pointer.

Comment: Your function template only gives a pointer and no indication of how many elements are at that address. How will that work?

Comment: Just use the built-in `lower_bound()` algorithm.

Comment: Don't use null when using C++; use 0.  This is not the solution, just a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype is

```
bool find(T *p, T value, int &index=null).
```

the function call is

```
iter = find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 5);
```

Conceptually, do these match? Does `end()` return a value? Is 5 an index?

Comment: Also, you cannot bind a non-const reference to a literal. I'd guess the `find` here is `std::find`, but apparently that's not what the OP wants.